# Date wont show in django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models

`DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)` in my django model.py file and everything is working fine but the problem is it won't show data/time in django admin panel.

Comment: do you intend to edit it from admin section or you just want to display it there?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add that field to `list_display`:

in `admin.py`:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  # "PostAdmin" is used for e.g purposes
[..]

    list_display = (.., 'created_at',)

[..]
```

Comment: lass ExitingLabor(models.Model):
    AdharNo = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=12, max_length=12)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    PhoneNumber = models.DecimalField(max_length=10, max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, null=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
this is my model and admin.py      admin.site.register(ExitingLabor) i allredy register my model so can please explian answer brifly

Answer (score 1):

when you set:

```
 DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

it will add your object that moment that you post the object, so if you want to select manually, you have to set:

```
 DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)
```

then it will show your Date field in your admin panel model.

Comment: you are right sir but if i will set auto_now_add=false then it will no longer tack date and time automatically ,i want my admin to show date wise data show change True to false wont help me

Comment: @Milan i really can't understand what are you trying to say... if you want to display the time that post created, just use list_display in admin.py and pass your Date field, or if u want display your Field in the object model with current time, import timezone from django.utils, and set your Date field like this: DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True), i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your date modified field may not display when editing an object since it is a read only value. In admin.py, try setting `readonly_fields = ("date_modified",)`, replacing date_modified with whatever you named your DateTimeField